# Why does FXMLLoader not initialize fields when a field is declared as a super-type

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

When I declare a field player as shown below:

```
class Controller{
    @FXML Shape player;
}
```

.fxml file - `<Rectangle fx:id="player" ...\>` 
Where in the `Controller`, `player` is declared as a super type (`Shape`), and in the fxml file
it is declared as a subtype.

I declare player as `Shape`, instead of `Rectangle`, because I have multiple similar fxml files, and the program decides, during runtime, which one to load. Every fxml file has a player object of some child class of `Shape`

My problem is that when a field is declared as the super type, fxml loader doesn't initialize that field. I would like to know a work-around to this problem.

A minimum reproducible example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test2 extends Application {
    @FXML Shape player;
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(
                FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("t.fxml"))
        );
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        System.out.println(player); //prints null
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <Rectangle fx:id="player" x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40"/>
</Pane>
```

Comment: The field is initialized in the controller, not in the `Applicaation` instance. You haven't even declared a controller class in the FXML.

Comment: _**My problem is that when a field is declared as the super type, fxml loader doesn't initialize that field**_ are you sure ? Is it initialized if you define it as `Rectangle player` ?

Comment: Also, `Controller` isn't a supertype of anything you posted in the question...

Comment: I am sorry. it is not because of using a super type. But I am not able to initialize the fields in my program. I will edit the question after finding the cause

Comment: Also: "I have multiple similar fxml files, and the program decides, during runtime, which one to load". Each FXML file should have a different controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized in the controller. Typically to create controllers, you specify a `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML (though there are other ways to do this). Your `test2` class [sic] is not the controller class (and even if it were, the instance on which `start()` is invoked would not be the controller).

The following modification of your code demonstrates that fields declared as a superclass type are indeed initialized as you would expect:

Controller.java:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.supertype;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

public class Controller{
    @FXML Shape player;
    
    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println(player);
    }
}
```

t.fxml (note `fx:controller` attribute):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefHeight="400.0"
    prefWidth="600.0"
    fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.supertype.Controller">
    <Rectangle fx:id="player" x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" />
</Pane>
```

Test2.java:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.supertype;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test2 extends Application {
    @FXML Shape player;
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(
                FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("t.fxml"))
        );
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This generates the expected output:

```
Rectangle[id=player, x=20.0, y=20.0, width=40.0, height=40.0, fill=0x000000ff]
```

Comment: "and even if it were, the instance on which start() is invoked would not be the controller" - could you please explain this. If I write the lines `FXMLLoader loader = ...;`
`loader.setController(this)`, inside the start() method, will 'the' test2 Object become the Controller?

Comment: @febot Yes, that would specify the current object as the controller. But it wouldn’t work using the `fx:controller` attribute. (Either way is bad design. The `Application` class is supposed to manage application lifecycle, not act as a controller, so you are violating the principle of single responsibility.)